# How to keep stored data even when an application update is done?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, data-storage

My question is simple :

I have a "flag" stored in SharredPreference but when the user is doing an application update, this data is ereased. Is there a way to keep data stored even if the user is doing an application update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I know you have only two choices - write it in a file or save it in the database.  I always put the data in the db, from witch they are loaded at program start.  Just have a table with the prefs in it and you are sure, that your data is not deleted, even after updating.  The database interface is easy to use and lean - therefor I use it.